# Ordering a list of objects by another object's property in C#

Tags: c#, sorting

We have a system that is based around Events that Users are invited to [UserInvite].

Currently, I have a page that lists all the Users invited to an Event; they can be sorted by various properties, such as Surname [ascending and descending]. All fine and dandy, but now I'm required to additionally sort by a UserInvite property: DateEdited [again asc/desc]. I've been using an extension method that takes in a string of the property name to sort by, but this won't work for another class's property.

Notes:

1. UserInvite has a method to get by Event and User which always returns a single UserInvite [or null if no invite was found].
2. The current EventID is held in the Master page so can be reached on the page that lists the Users

**What is the best way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a route from the `Event` to the `UserInvite`? If so, simply walk the relation. Actually, the **simplest** approach is to re-expose this date on the `Event` - i.e.

```
public DateTime InviteDate {get {return Invite.Date;}} // or similar
```

and order by `InviteDate` - but you can also use a string like "Invite.Date" and split it by dots - for example, [here's](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/7d931ec0e2356d21) something similar for `IQueryable<T>` - although it doesn't handle `null` at the moment.

Comment: The only working solution I've come up with was to add the UserInvite property into the User class.